# How do we import large datasets from Google BigQuery to R?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How do we import large datasets from Google BigQuery to R ?

I tried using the BigQuery package and tried importing. I am able to succeed in importing smaller datasets but not the huge ones

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM Table name"

todo_copies <- query_exec(sql, project = 'data-warehouse', dataset = 'name', useLegacySql = FALSE)
```

> bytes processed Error: Requested Resource Too Large to Return
>   [responseTooLarge]

Comment: Does the query work if you paste it in to BQ web UI?

Comment: If you just want the whole table, use an export instead of a query

Comment: exporting will cause memory problems on local PC so i would like to get the data on R from big query as dataframe. This query is written in R to get the data from big query to R

Answer (score 1):

The message refers to a limit related to the [Maximum response size](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#queries) for query jobs in BQ. It can be managed if you [write to a detination table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#large-results); however, most likely this option don't meet your needs.

Please note that R documentation indicates that [query_exec is being deprecated](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigrquery/versions/1.2.0/topics/query_exec) in favor of bq_project_query and from other threads like [How to load large datasets to R from BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138048/how-to-load-large-datasets-to-r-from-bigquery), it is suggested to [adjust the page_size property](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/a3ef603f36495bc13d9a5f5081010084bf3c146c/R/bq-download.R#L35-L37):

> "It should be adjusted when an error responseTooLarge appears"