# Running a .sql file from R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a few .sql files which aggregate a number of tables/views in a SQL Database. I want to be able to direct R to a specific sql file and execute it and return the results in a dataframe.

Googling around it seems that I can only grab actual tables/views which are in the database or I have to rewrite the sql query and run that through the package RODBC.

In python this can be done with pd.read_sql_query

Comment: You have to make a connection to your database via `RODBC` or another package before you can execute SQL commands against a database. If the data exists within R, you can use the library `sqldf` to run SQL queries against in-memory data.

Comment: Connecting is fine - even with sqldf it looks like I will need to paste in the query to run (which I can just do with RODBC). I don't want to paste in the query into R, instead I have the query code in a .sql file and I just need to get R to execute that sql file and return the data which is what pd.read_sql_query can do

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from reading the .sql file into R as a single character string and then sending that to the db via your RODBC connection like you would any other query you typed in yourself. There's a package called **squr** (possibly only on github) that does that sort of thing (and probably a lot more than you want).

Comment: And the important thing is that it needs to be a **single character string**, when you read in the raw file you need to be cautious of line breaks and comments.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, there's a few comments all around my sql code but if that's the only way I'll have to remove them

Comment: It's not that hard at all. I have my own home grown system (forked from squr) where I have whole packages with dozens of sql files, many of them have comments. It's really not that big a deal.

Comment: `sql <- paste(readLines("myfile.sql"), collapse = "\n")` .  Now `sql` is an R variable holding the SQL string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the contents of an .sql file into an R script to run a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853322/how-to-read-the-contents-of-an-sql-file-into-an-r-script-to-run-a-query)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck how does that deal with comments in the code?

Answer (score 12):

You can utilize the readr-package in conjunction with DBI and odbc

```
install.packages("readr")
library("DBI")
library("odbc") 
library("readr") 
df <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = read_file('Query.sql'))
```

Comment: Also, remember that when formatting SQL queries for R you might want to utilize SET NOCOUNT ON to prevent the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages.

Comment: I cant edit the response above so I will add some insight here below. I you find that queries that work perfectly in SQL does not work with R using "SET NOCOUNT ON" might do it for you. You might also want to experiment with specifying a particular DB and not.