# Using Where Clause with Dates When Reading SQL Query in R

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I am attempting to query an Oracle datebase from R using the SQL function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886192/11918054).

When I complete an easy query, such as

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE_1'
```

the query executes fine. However, when I add a conditional date statement to the query, such as

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE START_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-2018' AND '30-JUN-2019'
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch =
>   prefetch, : ORA-00904: "30-JUN-2019": invalid identifier

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact error appears to be that you didn't escape the single quotes you placed around the date literals in your R query string.  But, fixing that still leaves the problem that your date literals are invalid for Oracle.  I recommend using this:

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE START_DT BETWEEN DATE '2018-07-01' AND DATE '2019-06-30'"
```

You could also use the `TO_DATE` function, e.g. `TO_DATE('01-JUL-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, but this is a bit harder to read than using the `DATE` keyword.

Comment: It was a mistake, assume the DATE column is in reality named START_DT. Thanks for flagging; This was sloppy question writing. Apologies

Comment: @Parfait `I am attempting to query an Oracle datebase` ... date literals in Oracle have their own rules.

Comment: @Parfait the OP should avoid using a column name of "DATE" for just this reason. The "DATE" keyword has meaning in Oracle, and should therefore be avoided when thinking up identifier names.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Any idea how to handle aliases? It seems like when I have quotes within quotes, see below, my query breaks :/

sql <- "SELECT PROG_ID AS "PROGRAM" FROM TABLE_1 WHERE START_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-2018' AND '30-JUN-2019''"

Comment: 1) `PROGRAM` is not an Oracle keyword, so it does not require escaping in double quotes, and 2) if it did, then you just need to escape the double quotes in your R string with backslash, e.g. `\"PROGRAM\"`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'll just omit all single quotes in the original query for aliases. Usually keep them in there as that changes their color in our Oracle DB software (Toad) so it makes it easier to read in that environment, but seems like they don't play well with R. Thanks again for the help Tim!