# RStudio - ODBC connection with SQL query taken from sql file

Tags: r

I have my ODBC query to connect to Teradata and just wonder if I can read in the SQL file as oppose to have SQL code in? I am trying to find R function for Python's `pd.read_sql_query(f, con)` where f is my SQL file with code.

So for my connection, it would change from:

```
con <- function(){
  

  query <- paste0("
                  SELECT * FROM table1
         
                  
                  ")
  
  print(queryData(query))
  
}

con<- data.frame(con())
```

to

```
con <- function(){
  

  query <- "SQL_code.sql"
  
  print(queryData(query))
  
}

con<- data.frame(con())
```

Comment: see [dbGetQuery](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbGetQuery.html)

Answer (score 0):

read your sql from a file:

```
sql_query <- read.delim('/path/SQL_code.sql', header = FALSE) %>% as.character()
```

then define the connection and use it:

```
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect(...)
dbGetQuery(db, sql_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this?

```
library(DBI)
library(readr)
df <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = read_file('SQL_code.sql'))
# con is your connection
```

If it does not solve your problem, there may be some solutions here: [How to read the contents of an .sql file into an R script to run a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853322/how-to-read-the-contents-of-an-sql-file-into-an-r-script-to-run-a-query)